# MVC Editor Template accessing common data for multiple records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I want to have a list of editable rows in a table for my object

```
class Widget
{
    string shape;
    string color;
}
```

The color will be coming from a drop down list, so I have a View model like this

```
class WidgetListViewModel
{
    List<Widget> widgets;
    SelectList colorsSelectList;
}
```

and I have an EditorTemplate (WidgetEditorTemplate) for Widget.

here is how the template would be called in the view:

```
for(int i=0; i< in WidgetListViewModel.widgets.Count; i++)
{
    EditorFor(WidgetListViewModel.widgets[i], "WidgetEditorTemplate");
}
```

My problem is, in the WidgetEditorTemplate, how can I access the colorsSelectList?

I know I could just add colorsSelectList to the Widget model (or new viewmodel) but then I would have to load colorsSelectList for each widget record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you shouldn't have to use a for loop. If you use EditorFor on a list, it should automatically call the Widget editor for each item in the list.

That aside, I know it's not what you want to hear, but I think your bet option is to add the selected color to the Widget view model. The idea of a view model is that it should contain all of the data you need to render the view. In this case, you need the color information to render the view, so it should go in the view model.

Another option is to put the Widget stuff in a partial view instead of an editor template. Use the server-side RenderPartial to include it when the page is first loaded. When the color is changed, you can do an ajax callback to re-render the partial using the new color. This route gives you a callback which may be too slow, but it lets you just pass in the selected color as a parameter instead of having to store it on either model.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks for the input. (The reason I put the editor in the list is because that's the only way I can get model binding working properly for lists)

Comment: When working with lists, I have had more luck using custom helpers to tell the binder what to do, especially with partial views. There's an MVC 2 example here that is easy enough to convert to Razor: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/